# VectorError: xlGetChannelIndex failed (XL_ERR_HW_NOT_PRESENT)

Tags: python, can-bus

Hello I am using python with can analyzer hardware vn1610

```
import time
import can
count=0
a=0
for i in range(1,1000):  # zero to max range ( 0 - 2048 )
  a=a+1
  print(a)       #code stops running at a=64[enter image description here][1]
  bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='vector', app_name=None, channel=0,bitrate=500000)
  msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=i, data=[0x02,0x11,0x02,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00, 0x00, 0x00],dlc=3, extended_id=False)
  bus.send(msg)
  print ("Request msg:",msg)
  response=bus.recv(0.02) 
  print ("Response msg:",response)
```

I am getting can.interfaces.vector.exceptions.VectorError: xlGetChannelIndex failed (XL_ERR_HW_NOT_PRESENT) as a error. What is causing this error?

Comment: CAN messages are usually manufacturer specific (not counting to some small subset). This message, however, looks like that your CAM analyzer is not connected to the CAN bus.

Comment: @Mika72 i have connected the hardware, it works till a=64 and then it throws the error --> can.interfaces.vector.exceptions.VectorError: xlGetChannelIndex failed (XL_ERR_HW_NOT_PRESENT)

Comment: You are creating new interface/virtual channel everytime. Create it once before `for` loop and it should work.

Comment: @Swanand thanks man, It worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is stopping because you are creating a new interface everytime.

Probably CANalyzer supports maximum of 64 interfaces [*citation needed*] and that is why it stops after a = 64.

You don't have to create interface everytime. 
Move

`bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='vector', app_name=None, channel=0,bitrate=500000)`

out of `for` loop and your code should work. As you don't have to create interface again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Well this royally set me back 6hrs, trust the library they said...

I just recently rediscovered this issue because someone decided to give `app_name` a default value of "CANalyzer" in the constructor of VectorBus in canLib.py, this causes it to only go through channels that have been configured for that app_name "CANalyzer" using the `set_application_config()` of course since none were setup, it errors just like it would if no interface was connected.

As for my fix:

```
bus = can.interface.Bus(interface='vector', channel='0', receive_own_messages=True, bitrate=500000, app_name=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a bus once in a code, you can also create signal bus for various channels, as in:

```
    can.interface.Bus(interface='vector', channel='0,1,2,3',receive_own_messages=True,bitrate=500000)
```